# to find max value from a given table in sql express

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i am trying to retrieve latest data from my database table.
i am using max(columnName) but not having result to my liking.
i keep getting column name instead of any value

please help me out in this...

the code for retrieving max value is like this

```
            dbConnection dbCon = new dbConnection();
            con = dbCon.doConnection();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();


            String query = "select max(studentNo) from studentInfo;";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            { 
                String x=reader["studentNo"].ToString();

            }
```

here the studentNo is the column name whose value i need to extract and it is of int type
while printing the string x on my application i get studentNo instead of the value.
now i am short of clue to solve the prob because i can't find anything wrong with the code.
do help me in this one

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the way you are accessing the value, you can change two things here.  Either access the reader by index or name the column appropriately in the query.

```
select max(studentNo) as StudentNo from studentInfo;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query outputs one row and one column of data, so you might consider using `ExecuteScalar()` instead of `ExecuteReader()`:

```
dbConnection dbCon = new dbConnection();
con = dbCon.doConnection();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();


String query = "select max(studentNo) from studentInfo;";
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = query;
String x = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give alias to your select after applying aggregate function

i.e. select max(studentNo) as NO from studentInfo

and while reading it

String x=reader["NO"].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set the correct alias do the column:

```
select max(studentNo) as 'studentNo' from studentInfo;
```

And second, you may want to assign a database to the table:

```
select max(studentNo) as studentNo from databaseName..studentInfo;
```